# about fatfree framework query

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

I have this kind of weirdness with a update query in fat free frameworks

```
public function updateTransactionSalesFlush() {

    $this->load(array('active=1 AND void=0'));
    if (!$this->dry()) {            
        $data = array('salestemp' => 0);
        $this->copyFrom($data);
        $this->update();            
    }
}
```

This function update only the first record of selected but not all of them as expected. Am I doing something wrong or it's a bug??

The following query work fine using exec function:

```
 UPDATE transactions SET salestemp=0 WHERE active= 1 AND void= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/databases

> By default, a data mapper's `load()` method retrieves only the first record that matches the specified criteria. If you have more than one that meets the same condition as the first record loaded, you can use the `skip()` method for navigation:

Comment: thx, it's clear now, but iterate all records using skip() metod to update it  seem very unuseful. Much better using exec() method or not??

Answer (score 1):

The `load()` method loads all the records matching the specified criteria but maps only *one* record at a time.

You need then to use the `next()` or `skip()` methods to navigate through the set of records.

Your code updates only the first record because it lacks a loop. Here's how to fix it:

```
public function updateTransactionSalesFlush() {

    $this->load(array('active=1 AND void=0'));
    while (!$this->dry()) {
        $this->salestemp=0;
        $this->update();
        $this->next();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could call the `find()` method instead of `load()`:

```
public function updateTransactionSalesFlush() {

    $records=$this->find(['active=1 AND void=0']);
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $record->salestemp=0;
        $record->update();
    }
}
```

Of course, if you're updating a big number of records, you'd better execute a single `UPDATE` statement via the `exec()` method:

```
public function updateTransactionSalesFlush() {

    $this->db->exec('UPDATE '.$this->table.' SET salestemp=0 WHERE active=1 AND void=0');
}
```

Comment: It may be a good idea for an improvement. The `update` method may optionally accept a filter, the same way the `remove` method does.

Comment: Then it would require two arguments: the filter and the key/values pairs.

Comment: I was initially thinking to use object's properties as key/value pairs, but that may not necessarily be intuitive, and it wouldn't work on expressions like `key1=key2+1`. So as much as I hate the idea of vanilla SQL, I need to agree that it is too tricky to do it with data mapper.